# How does this question on matrix multiplication work?

Tags: matrices

So, there was this solved question in my reference book-
$$ AB = A \space \space \space \space BA=B$$
And I was given the following options-
$$1. A = I$$
$$2. B = I$$
$$3. A = A^2$$
$$4. B = B^2$$

And according to the book only the last two are true. But shouldn't the first two be true as well?
since, 
$$AB = A$$
$$A^{-1}AB = I$$
$$B = I$$
Similar should be true for $A$ by symmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Would the first two options be correct if $A, B$ were singular?

Comment: Sorry, I was sleeping

Comment: @ShaheAnsar No problem.